# In the U.S., what are the requirements for being an Executive airport?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, airport-design

Are there statutory or regulatory criteria for a facility to be called, say, Elbonia Executive Airport as opposed to County, Municipal, Regional, Field, or something else? Is it strictly marketing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a marketing distinction -- generally applied to a major GA reliever airport designed to serve light/business jets in [design categories](http://aireform.com/faas-airport-reference-codes/) B-II and C-II or perhaps C-III.  This is distinguished from general purpose GA relievers as a light GA reliever may be designed to service a maximum design category of A-II, B-I, or B-II; it is also distinguished from County, Municipal, or Regional airports as while they are similarly sized in terms of design category, a County, Municipal, or Regional airport is the primary airport for that area as opposed to being a reliever for a larger scheduled service airport.

Comment: Can you clarify these categories?

Comment: I added a link to clarify the categories.